# SQL - Find the Top Level Parent and Multiply Quantities

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables which track part numbers as well as the hierarchy of assemblies.

Table: Config

```
  ConfigNum  AssemblyNum  Qty
     1            A        1
     1            B        2
     1            C        2
     2            A        1
     2            C        1
```

Table: SubAssembly

```
SubAssembly  PartNum  Qty
     A          AA     2
     A          BB     4
     A          CC     2
     A          DD     4
     B          EE     4
     B          FF     8
     AA         AAA    2
```

I would like to create a flat version of these tables which shows the ConfigNum (Top level parent) with all associated assembly and part numbers, for each ConfigNum in the Config table. The column Config.AssemblyNum is equivalent to SubAssembly.SubAssembly.

The Subassembly table shows the partent to child relation ship between parts. For example Assembly 'A' has a child assembly 'AA'. Since 'AA' exists in the SubAssembly Column is it self an assembly and as you can see it has a child part 'AAA'. 'AAA' does not exist in the SubAssemly columns therefore it is the last child in the series.

I would also like to have an accurate quantity count of each part based on multiplying of parent to child down the chain.

For example in the output:

```
(Total Qty of AAA) = (Qty A) x (Qty AA) x (Qty AAA)
4 = 1 x 2 x 2
```

Example Output table: (for Config 1)

```
 ConfigNum   SubAssembly   PartNum   TotalQty
     1            A            AA        2
     1            A            BB        4
     1            A            CC        2
     1            A            DD        4
     1            B            EE        8
     1            B            FF        16
     1            A            AAA       4
```

Any suggestion on how to complete this task would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** I have been able to create this code based on suggestions made in the answers. 
I am still having trouble getting the quantities to multiply down. 
I have received the error "Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "PartQty" of recursive query "RCTE"."

```
;WITH RCTE (AssemblyNum, PartNum, PartQty, Lvl) AS
(
    SELECT  AssemblyNum, PartNum, PartQty, 1 AS Lvl 
    FROM SP_SubAssembly r1
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SP_SubAssembly r2 WHERE r1.AssemblyNum = r2.PartNum)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT rh.AssemblyNum, rc.PartNum, (rc.PartQty * rh.PartQty), Lvl+1 AS Lvl 
    FROM dbo.SP_SubAssembly rh
    INNER JOIN RCTE rc ON rh.PartNum = rc.AssemblyNum
)
SELECT CB.ID, CB.ConfigNum, CB.PartNum, CB.PartQty, r.AssemblyNum, r.PartNum, SUM(r.PartQty * COALESCE(CB.PartQty,1)) AS TotalQty
FROM SP_ConfigBOM CB
FULL OUTER JOIN RCTE r ON CB.PartNum = r.AssemblyNum
WHERE CB.ConfigNum IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY CB.ConfigNum
```

Thanks,

Comment: there isn't any PartNum='A' like in your first row.

Comment: You're correct. I updated the table to properly reflect this. Thanks, @mcNets

Comment: is there any field that links 'AA' and 'AAA' other than both have 'A'?

Comment: The links are all only found in the SubAssembly table. Ie) Assembly A has Part AA. Part AA is it self an assembly which contains Part AAA and so on. If a PartNum is not found in the SubAssembly column then it is the last child of the series

Comment: but there isn't any record that SubAssembly='AA' and PartNum='AAA', does it?

Comment: Yes, In the SubAssembly table you can see that relation in the last row. The first row of the SubAssembly Table defines 'A' as the parent assembly of part 'AA'. The last row of the SubAssemblyTable defines that the child part 'AA' to have a grandchild 'AAA'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this problem I think you must use a recursive query. In fact I think SubAssembly table should have some ProductID field other than SubAssembly to easily identify the main product that contains assemblies.

You can find a similar example in [SLQ Server documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx).

Can check it here: http://rextester.com/FQYI80157

Change the Qty in Config table to change the final result.

```
create temp table t1 (cfg int, part varchar(10), qty int);
create temp table t2 (part varchar(10), sasm varchar(10), qty int);
insert into t1 values (1,'A',2);
insert into t2 values ('A','AA',2);
insert into t2 values ('A','BB',4);
insert into t2 values ('A','CC',2);
insert into t2 values ('A','DD',4);
insert into t2 values ('AA','AAA',2);


WITH cte(sasm, part, qty) 
AS (
    SELECT sasm, part, qty 
    FROM #t2 WHERE part = 'A'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT p.sasm, p.part, p.qty * pr.qty
    FROM cte pr, #t2 p
    WHERE p.part = pr.sasm
  )
SELECT #t1.cfg, cte.part, cte.sasm, SUM(cte.qty * COALESCE(#t1.qty,1)) as total_quantity
FROM cte
left join #t1 on cte.part = #t1.part
GROUP BY #t1.cfg, cte.part, cte.sasm;
```

This is the result:

```
+------+------+----------------+
| part | sasm | total_quantity |
+------+------+----------------+
|   A  | AA   |        4       |
+------+------+----------------+
|   A  | DD   |        8       |
+------+------+----------------+
|  AA  | AAA  |        4       |
+------+------+----------------+
|   A  | BB   |        8       |
+------+------+----------------+
|   A  | CC   |        4       |
+------+------+----------------+
```

Comment: Your answer was a big help, thank you. I am still having trouble getting the multiplication of quantities to work and am receiving an error when attempting to run in SQL Server 2014. I have updated the original post to show what progress I have made. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: sql server? it was about postgresql initially, does it?

Comment: I don't believe so. Maybe I tagged the question wrong? This is my first post so I believe I only marked it SQl, SQL - Server. Your answer still helped a lot as most of the syntax seems the same

Comment: where is the problem now?

Comment: I am able to get the query to work and pull the list of child to parent relationships. But the Multiplication of PartQty gives me the error "Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "PartQty" of recursive query "RCTE"."

Comment: ok, I've updated the answer, now works for SQL Server. Check the rextester   link. http://rextester.com/FQYI80157

Answer (score 0):

```
 insert into #Temp
 SELECT   A.[ConfigNum] ,
          A.[AssemblyNum],
          B.[PartNum],
          A.[Qty],
          A.QTY * B.Qty TotalQty
      INTO #Temp
      FROM  [Config] A,
            [SubAssembly] B
      WHERE A.[AssemblyNum] = B.[SubAssembly]

     SELECT   A.[ConfigNum] ,
             A.[AssemblyNum],
             A.[PartNum],
             A.[Qty],
             A.TotalQty  
    FROM #Temp A 
    union 
    SELECT   A.[ConfigNum] ,
             A.[AssemblyNum],
             B.[PartNum],
             A.[Qty],
             A.TotalQty *   B.Qty 
    FROM #Temp A,
     [SubAssembly] B
     WHERE 
             A.[PartNum] = B.[SubAssembly]
```